# How to get started organising a community for carsharing in a village?

Tags: physical-communities, legal, community-organizing

[Carsharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carsharing) is a model of short-term car rental in which people can rent cars by the hour or even by the minute.  Commercial operators tend to focus on cities, and rarely have offers in smaller communities.  In some villages, [community efforts exist](https://www.tagesschau.de/wirtschaft/technologie/themenwoche-elektrodorfauto-101.html), but those remain rare.  For people who need a car at most once or twice a month, private ownership is a very uneconomical and unecological solution, and carsharing is an attractive alternative.

In a village of around 2,000 inhabitants in Central Europe, how would one get started with an initiative for community carsharing?  How would one reach potentially interested people, get their support and interest, and get them to join an organisation that can proceed with concrete steps to make community carsharing happen?